# Do we need a unique "rstudio" tag?

Tags: discussion, tags, r

I've observed that there are a small number of questions tagged as "rstudio." Is this strictly necessary? It seems to me that it would prevent splintering of R-related questions across multiple tags if one were a synonym for the other.

Comment: Consider accepting chl's answer as it seems to have settled the issue.

Answer (score 16, accepted):

Thanks for bringing our attention to that! I have removed this tag from the three threads. Obviously, we don't need such a tag on Cross Validated as it targets a particular UI specific to R (even if this is probably the most useful and least intrusive :-).

Comment: My concern with removing it is it will likely get remade and reused. I suggest that if it happens again any time soon and stays around, it might be worth making it a synonym of `r`.

Comment: On the other hand, there's also the distinct possibility, now or in the future, that `rstudio` could be just as valid a tag as `r`, since it adds a lot of functionality (and presumably will add more), related to which there might ultimately be valid questions (with statistical content or that require statistical knowledge to answer) that don't apply to `r`. (We can undo merging/mapping one tag to another? Or not?)

Comment: IMHO there is not need for such tag and it should be removed. RStudio is just a GUI, if we make tags for such things we should also consider `vi`, `emacs` etc. tags. RStudio alone is incapable of doing anything related to statistics or data visualization (while being the best available GUI for R).

Comment: @Glen_b My main concern is that RStudio is really just a tool, just like Emacs ESS, as Tim said, not a statistical package. It is much like creating an [Hadley-verse](http://adolfoalvarez.cl/the-hitchhikers-guide-to-the-hadleyverse/) tag, IMO. (P.S. No, we cannot undo merging.)

Comment: @Tim Here's an example of the kind of question that might relate to statistical content -- in a discussion of how to organize a large number of statistical projects -- what I'd regard as bang on topic -- RStudio does provide tools for that in a way that R doesn't (at least not 'built-in'). If those aspects grow, RStudio could *easily* be the subject of specifically statistical question that don't apply to R.

Comment: @Glen_b ok, but how many other topics like this possibly exist? I would say not many. Also, IMHO, this is not less "technical" issue then programming questions on R.

Answer (score 11):

No, we do not need a distinct rstudio tag because rstudio is simply a convenient interface to R, not a separate language with its own peculiarities. Making rstudio a synonym of r appears to solve any residual need to consolidate R-related tags.